Specific product attribute custom dropdown for WooCommerce variation selection
In WooCommerce, I have an attribute called License Type. This attribute has 2 terms:

Single Site License
Multi Site License

With the above, I'm trying to create a custom select dropdown, where the option contains the variation ID.
For example, my product has both of those variations assigned. For that product:

Single Site License has an ID of 210
Multi Site License has an ID of 211

So, I'm looking for my output to look something like this:
<select name="pa_license-type" id="pa_license-type">
  <option value="single-site-license" data-variation-id="210">Single Site License</option>
  <option value="multi-site-license" data-variation-id="211">Multi Site License</option>
</select>

To make this dynamic, for each product, I've attempted the following:
if ($product->is_type('variable')) :
  $product_id = $product->get_id();
  $available_variations = $product->get_children();

  $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

  foreach ($attributes as $attribute_name => $options) :
      $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute_name);
    $terms = get_terms(array(
      'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
      'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) :

      $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label($taxonomy);
      echo '<label for="' . esc_attr($taxonomy) . '">' . esc_html($attribute_label) . '</label>';
      echo '<select name="' . esc_attr($taxonomy) . '" id="' . esc_attr($taxonomy) . '">';

      $variation_ids_map = array();

      foreach ($terms as $term) :
          $term_slug = $term->slug;
          $current_variation_id = '';

          foreach ($available_variations as $variation_id_candidate) :
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id_candidate);
            if ($variation && has_term($term_slug, $taxonomy, $variation->get_id())) :
              $current_variation_id = $variation->get_id();
              break;
            endif;
          endforeach;
          
          $variation_ids_map[$term_slug] = $current_variation_id;
          echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($term_slug) . '" data-variation-id="' . esc_attr($current_variation_id) . '">' . esc_html($term->name) . '</option>';

      endforeach;

      echo '</select>';
    endif;

  endforeach;
endif;
?>

But that yields:
<select name="pa_license-type" id="pa_license-type">
  <option value="single-site-license" data-variation-id="">Single Site License</option>
  <option value="multi-site-license" data-variation-id="">Multi Site License</option>
</select>

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?
Images of backend if reference needed:



There are some mistakes and complications. Try the following simplified code version:
global $product; // If needed

if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
    
    $taxonomy = 'pa_license-type'; // Targeted global product attribute taxonomy
    $terms    = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through available variations
    foreach ( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id ); // Get the product variation object

        if ( $variation && $variation->exists() && $variation->variation_is_visible() ) {
            if ( $term = get_term_by('name', esc_html( $variation->get_attribute($taxonomy) ), $taxonomy) ) {
                $terms[$variation->get_id()] = $term;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( count($terms) > 0 ) {
        printf('<label for="%s">%s</label><select name="%s" id="%s">', 
            esc_attr($taxonomy), wc_attribute_label($taxonomy), esc_attr($taxonomy), esc_attr($taxonomy) );

        foreach ( $terms as $variation_id => $term ) {
            printf('<option value="%s" data-variation-id="%d">%s</option>', esc_attr($term->slug), $variation_id, esc_html($term->name) );
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}

It should work.

Hi Loic, the above doesn't print anything for me. A var_dump($terms); returns array(0) { }.

@Freddy I just tested that on a variable product targeting "pa_color" taxonomy, and it works, displaying the custom dropdown with all options (with the correct variation ID). See https://i.sstatic.net/I6ZkxqWk.png. So there is something wrong in your case: It could be a code implementation issue, a product setting issue or maybe a wrong attribute taxonomy. Note that each term of targeted taxonomy need to be assigned to product variation.

Why you don't use the WooCommerce default variable product attribute dropdown?

Are you placing your code in variable.php? I'm currently adding this to content-single-product.php, so unsure if it's to do with that? In regards to your second query, the answer is simply because I didn't know one existed out of the box! Is there a function I can pass on my template to render it (to see what it prints). But essentially, I have some custom add to cart functionality that I'm trying to create with this dropdown that involves passing the variation ID to the button e.g. ?add-to-cart=203&variation_id=&attribute_pa_license_type=single-site-license&redirect_to_cart=1

I Use a hooked function add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_table', function(){ // HERE the code } );… You can use the code from single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php template… but you need to define at least the variables $attributes and $available_variations that are defined in woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() function. But I still don't understand why you need a custom add to cart functionality. You should better explain things in your question.

Hi Loic, firstly, I managed to get your approach to work for me, but I did have to tweak it slightly. get_available_variations didn't return any results for me, but when I changed to get_children(), it works (foreach ($product->get_children() as $variation_id) :). Since this question is answered, I'll accept and close it off. I have created another question which explains more around the custom add to cart button, which you can see here if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78761200/creating-custom-add-to-cart-button-for-products-that-have-variations-in-woocomme

@Freddy get_available_variations was working for me. However, I updated my code with get_children instead. I will take a look at your new question.
