Creating custom add to cart button for variable products with variations in WooCommerce
I'm trying to create a custom button for products that have variations in WooCommerce.
For context, In WooCommerce, I have a product attribute called "License Type". This attribute has 2 terms:

Single Site License,
Multi Site License.

I have a product (with an ID of 203), which contains these two variations:

In my theme, I have an override for content-single.product.php template, where I have the following snippets:

The select dropdown for a user to determine which license they want:

<?php

global $product;

if ($product->is_type('variable')) :

  $taxonomy = 'pa_license_type';
  $terms = array();

  foreach ($product->get_children() as $variation_id) :
    $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);

    if (!$variation) :
      continue;
    endif;

    // Get the attribute value for the specified taxonomy
    $attribute_value = $variation->get_attribute($taxonomy);

    if ($term = get_term_by('slug', esc_html($attribute_value), $taxonomy)) :
      $terms[$variation->get_id()] = $term;
    endif;

  endforeach;

  if (count($terms) > 0) :
    printf('<label for="%s">%s</label><select name="%s" id="%s">', esc_attr($taxonomy), wc_attribute_label($taxonomy), esc_attr($taxonomy), esc_attr($taxonomy));
    foreach ($terms as $variation_id => $term) :
      printf('<option value="%s" data-variation-id="%d">%s</option>', esc_attr($term->slug), $variation_id, esc_html($term->name));
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';
  endif;

endif;

?>


The custom button markup:

<?php if ( $product  && $product->is_in_stock() ) :

  $product_id = $product->get_id();
  $add_to_cart_url = esc_url( '?add-to-cart=' . $product_id . '&redirect_to_cart=1' );

  if ($product->is_type('variable')) : ?>
    <a id="variationBtn" href="<?= $add_to_cart_url; ?>">
      <?php _e( 'Add to Cart (Variation)', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
  <?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?= $add_to_cart_url; ?>">
      <?php _e( 'Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>


The JS that controls the href on the variation button based on the variation ID of the selected license from the dropdown:

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const variationBtn = document.getElementById('variationBtn');
  const licenseTypeSelect = document.getElementById('pa_license_type');

  function updateAddToCartUrl() {
    const selectedOption = licenseTypeSelect.options[licenseTypeSelect.selectedIndex];
    const selectedLicenseType = selectedOption.value;
    const variationId = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-variation-id');

    const addToCartUrl = `?add-to-cart=<?php echo $product_id; ?>&variation_id=${variationId}&attribute_pa_license-type=${selectedLicenseType}&redirect_to_cart=1`;
    variationBtn.setAttribute('href', addToCartUrl);
  }

  // Init on page load with default values
  updateAddToCartUrl();

  // Update the URL when the license type changes
  licenseTypeSelect.addEventListener('change', updateAddToCartUrl);
});

E.g A sample rendered HTML view of my button:
<a id="variationBtn" href="?add-to-cart=203&amp;variation_id=211&amp;attribute_pa_license-type=single-site-license&amp;redirect_to_cart=1">Add to Cart (Variation)</a>

The desired functionality

User selects license type from dropdown
User clicks on add to cart button
System recognises which variation to add to the cart from the product and variation ID
User is redirected to cart automatically

The current results
Step 3 is where my approach isn't working.
My button href successfully updates with the variation ID on change etc. But, on click of the button, it doesn't add my product to the cart.

First, there are some small changes to make in your 2nd code snippet:
<?php if ( $product  && $product->is_in_stock() ) :
    $product_id      = $product->get_id();
    $add_to_cart_url = esc_url( '?add-to-cart=' . $product_id . '&redirect_to_cart=1' );
  
    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        printf('<a id="variationBtn" data-product_id="%d" href="%s">%s</a>', $product_id, $add_to_cart_url, __('Add to Cart (Variation)', 'woocommerce'));
    } else {
        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $add_to_cart_url, __('Add to Cart', 'woocommerce') );
    } ?>
<?php endif;?>

Then there are multiple mistakes in your JavaScript code (here I use jQuery as this JS library is used by WordPress and WooCommerce). Try the following instead:
jQuery(function($){
    if ( $('#variationBtn').length ) {
        const taxonomy = 'pa_license_type', 
            productID  = $('#variationBtn').data('product_id');

        var variationID = $('select[name='+taxonomy+']').find(":selected").data('variation-id'),
            selectedVal = $('select[name='+taxonomy+']').find(":selected").val();

        function changeAddToCartURL(){
            const addToCartUrl = '?add-to-cart='+productID+'&variation_id='+variationID+'&attribute_'+taxonomy+'='+selectedVal+'&redirect_to_cart=1';
            $('#variationBtn').attr('href', addToCartUrl);
        }

        // At start
        changeAddToCartURL();

        // On Change
        $('select[name='+taxonomy+']').on('change', function(){
            variationID = $(this).find(":selected").data('variation-id'),
            selectedVal = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            changeAddToCartURL();
        });
    }
});

Now you will be able adding to cart the selected variation (license type).

Hi Loic, thanks again for the pointers. I can confirm that I made the edits as per your above suggestions, but my cart is still empty. I'm sure you've tested your side it was functional. Is there anyway to debug where in the process it's going wrong?

Ignore the above! Turns out I didn't check the "enable" variation checkbox against the variations, so WooComm had nothing to add. I can confirm your code did the trick for me - thanks!
